# On complexity of a particular prime problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-complexity

Is the following problem in $PH$ and is it complete for any class?

Problem: Is the $i$th bit of the $m$th prime $1$?

It appears to require a counting quantifier which has to demonstrate witness is the $m$th prime and since there is an unique witness is it in $UP^{PP}$?

Comment: It's in $P^{PP}$ because if you have an oracle that tells you the number of primes up to $n$ (which is in $PP$) then you can find the $m$th prime rapidly by binary search.

Comment: It was not clear to me we use polynomial number of calls. I guess it is obvious.